# check if list item is substring of a string

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, exception

I wrote this code to check if a list-item is a part of a string.

```
var postBackControl = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
var postBackNotRemoveRowsColumns = new List<string> { "button1", "button2", "button3", "button4" };
bool isPostBackExistInList = false;

if (postBackControl != null)
{
    isPostBackExistInList = postBackNotRemoveRowsColumns.Any(postBackControl.Contains);
}
```

but I got this crash:

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled {Cannot evaluate
>   expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the content of `postBackControl`?

Comment: What is `postBackControl.Contains`?

Comment: postBackControl is the auto generated id for button in asp.net, i want to check if the id (as string) contains one of the strings in list.

Comment: Also what method is this in? I'm not sure whether you understand what a `StackOverflowException` is but it basically says that you have some kind of recursive call that is not terminating. This means that some method call is being made that ultimately calls itself. I can't see anything in your code given that would do that...

Comment: @HimBromBeere: `postBackControl` will be a string that does have that method.

Comment: thanks for your comments, this code inside a method that return bool, i call this method only once !

Comment: However this code won´t cause the exception if you´re just running it once. Maybe there is an outer loop that you didn´t consider?

Comment: oh yes ! you are write, i forgot to delete a row for the method, i call it recursively. the problem is solved, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided will work if you are sure that it's a string inside your `Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]`: https://repl.it/C4ts/0

So most likely there is a problem outside of the scope you provided. Try to check if you have other places in code that could cause infinite recursion.